# Funny Martian Manhunter Comic

Tags: dc, episode-identification, martian-manhunter

I remember quickly reading this Martian Manhunter comic that was absolutely hilarious. In it, two guys (I think it was Blue Beetle and Booster Gold) steal MM's cookies. He gets so mad he basically turns into the Hulk and starts chasing them around Metropolis shouting "Coookie!"

I would LOVE to read that comic again. Does anyone know which issue it is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's [Martian Manhunter vol 2 issue 24](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Martian_Manhunter_Vol_2_24):

[image: It's the cover of the issue with Martian Manhunter sitting on a throne of cookies and some guys buried in cookies at his feet]